# UWP C# Toggleswitch inside Listview - How to get items of Row when clicked on Toggleswitch

Tags: c#, listview, uwp, toggleswitch

So i'm having this Listview with on Toggleswitch. What i want is to do is to fire an event like `ItemClick="Event_Overview_Teams_ItemClick"`
but with
`Toggled="TeamPresent_Toggled"`
and work on with the items like TeamID of the clicked row.

```
<ListView x:Name="Event_Overview_Teams" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="1787" Margin="0,48,0,10" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="Event_Overview_Teams_ItemClick" SelectionMode="None">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Width="900">
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TeamName" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding TeamName}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TeamID"   Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding TeamID}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TeamNumber" Grid.Column="2" Text="{Binding TeamNumber}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="TeamClass" Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding TeamClass}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="DeliverTime" Grid.Column="4" Text="{Binding DeliverTime}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                                    <!--<TextBlock x:Name="TeamPresent" Grid.Column="5" Text="{Binding TeamPresent}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />-->
                                    <ToggleSwitch x:Name="TeamPresent" Grid.Column="5" IsOn="{Binding TeamPresent}" Toggled="TeamPresent_Toggled"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you trigger the **TeamPresent_Toggled** event, you can get the viewmodel which bound with the current item by getting the **DataContext** of the ToggleSwitch. Then changing the property(e.g. TeamID) from the viewmodel you get.

```
private void TeamPresent_Toggled(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var toggle = (ToggleSwitch)sender;
    var dataContext = toggle.DataContext;
    MyViewModel dataItem = (MyViewModel)dataContext;
    dataItem.TeamID = "MyNewTeamId";
    ......
}
```